# Unable to run the flutter code getting error

Tags: gradle, flutter

Unable to run the flutter code getting error

> Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task
>   'javaPreCompileDebug' property 'compileClasspaths' during up-to-date
>   check. > Error snapshotting jar [flutter.jar]
>   Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Comment: At which directory did you install Flutter? `C:\Program Files` doesn't work because Flutter needs write permission in its install directory.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu and installed directory is having 777 permission

Comment: Try `git clean -xfd` `git pull` `flutter doctor` in your Flutter install directory.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
git clean -xfd 
git pull 
flutter doctor
```

in your Flutter install directory to fix your Flutter installation.

Comment: As it was showing  flutter update was 50 days old and on pull it get upgraded to new version which solve my problem

Comment: Glad to hear. Perhaps `flutter upgrade` had been enough already.

Comment: yes first i run 'flutter docter' which gave me the idea to upgrade then i use 'git clean -xfd 
git pull'